# BlackBerry objectlistfield development

Tags: blackberry

How to get the index of ObjectListField in BlackBerry so that on clicking one item in the object list ,we can retrieve the position of an item?

Comment: use getSelectedIndex() method

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code for getting the index :

```
int index =  yourObjectListField.getSelectedIndex();
```

And the following code to get the text:

```
String selectedText += yourObjectListField.get(yourObjectListField, yourObjectListField.getSelectedIndex());
```